# Why does this not work when split onto 2 lines?

Tags: c++

This line:

```
std::auto_ptr<Ogre::Root> lRoot (new Ogre::Root(lConfigFileName, lPluginsFileName, lLogFileName));
```

works fine.
However when I do this it doesn't:

```
std::auto_ptr<Ogre::Root> lRoot;
lRoot (new Ogre::Root(lConfigFileName, lPluginsFileName, lLogFileName));
```

And it reports: `error: no match for call to ‘(std::auto_ptr<Ogre::Root>) (Ogre::Root*)’`
As far as my limited understanding goes shouldn’t these do the same thing? Or am I missing something major?

Comment: Last time I checked, Ogre had its own smart pointer classes. Why don't you use them? Anyway, `auto_ptr` is deprecated. Forget about it.

Comment: That's how the OGRE tutorials are telling me to do it xD, I'm just restructuring the code a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first statement is a declaration of variable `lRoot` with initialisation (using the syntax of initialiser in parentheses).

The second is a declaration of default-initialised variable `lRoot`, followed by invoking `operator()` on the variable. (Note that [`std::auto_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) doesn't define such an operator).

To split this into two lines (still as one statement), you can just insert a line break anywhere whitespace is allowed:

```
std::auto_ptr<Ogre::Root> lRoot(
  new Ogre::Root(lConfigFileName, lPluginsFileName, lLogFileName));
```

To actually split this into a declaration and assignment (note that when split, it cannot be an initialisation), you could do this:

```
std::auto_ptr<Ogre::Root> lRoot;
lRoot.reset(new Ogre::Root(lConfigFileName, lPluginsFileName, lLogFileName));
```

Comment: Perfect, not only does it answer the question but gives a fix as well, will accept ASAP.

Comment: @handuel: In the future, if you *want* a fix it might be better to ask for it. There are tons of questions where the poster does not want to fix something (e.g. there is an obvious workaround) but rather to understand it.

Answer (score 7):

There is very little relation between the two snippets.

The first one declares and initializes the variable `lRoot`, nothing to see there.

The second snippet declares and default-initializes `lRoot` in the first line, but then it goes on to invoke [`operator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdte99aa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `lRoot` with an argument of type `Ogre::root*`. Since `std::auto_ptr` [does not define](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/auto_ptr/) an `operator()`, the compiler produces the given error.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Angew already mentions `.reset` in his answer, so that base is covered. I didn't because the question only asks "why?".

Comment: true that he only asks why, but the OP obviously has _no_ idea what he's doing and needs a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same thing!

You are not just splitting the statement into two lines. The two are two different statements..

You can split the first statement onto two lines like this:

```
std::auto_ptr<Ogre::Root> lRoot
    (new Ogre::Root(lConfigFileName, lPluginsFileName, lLogFileName));
```

And it would compile just fine because the multiple white spaces are ignored.

Comment: How would I split it onto two lines. (Or have the declaration in a .h and the initialisation in a constructor in .cpp)